# How to access viewcontrollers of spliviewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi In one of my ipad application I am used splitviewcontroller. My app actually working in IOS6 well, now new requirement came from the client. Based on client request I start porting app to IOS7. But while porting to IOS7 the viewcontroller views linked with spliviewcontroller Y positions are increasing 20 pixels due to that navigationbar and tableview is moving down  by 20 pixels from statusbar. It's working fine in IOS6 but in IOS7 only I am facing this issue.So please let me know how to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with iOS 7 and fixed it be turning off translucent navigation bar:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]){

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for IOS 7 :

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *leftNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: be careful of casting like that. It can cause crashes. you can use an if statement before to check, if([self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]]). this makes sure you don't accidentally cast it something that it's not.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a layout issue as KamilPyc pointed out it can be turned off using translucency. Or you can use this in the viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
}
```